# Using an aspect library in an AspectJ plugin in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, aspectj, gradle-plugin

I'm migrating an application from Maven to Gradle. The app is using AspectJ with custom AspectJ library. So the `aspectj-maven-plugin` setup looks as the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${aspect.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>com.someCompany.someTeam.someModule</groupId>
                <artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compileAspects</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.someCompany.someTeam.someModule</groupId>
            <artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
            <version>${someTeam.someModule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I've found several Gradle plugins for AspectJ (e.g. [this one](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/aspectj.gradle) seems to be official). However there are so little information and examples available that I can't decide on how to rewrite this simple setup.

Any ideas? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I am a Maven user, so I do not know much about Gradle or the plugin you mentioned. But what you need to do in order to use your aspect library is put it on the aspectpath. The plugin seems to have a [parameter](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/blob/master/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy#L140) for that. I hope you can figure out the rest by yourself.

Comment: @kriegaex yes, I'm trying it now. Hope it works for me

Comment: did you found the solution?

Comment: @JasonHuang wow, so much memories, it's been a year seen I was working on that.. yeah, kind of, I managed to solve it removing AspectJ altogether:)

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have used AspectJ in gradle file as

```
  compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.9'
  compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.9'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

Hope this helps.